# Fast preview not working in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I tried to restart the HTTP and MobileFirst server. one message came that faster preview can't be configured for this project. any solution??

[image: Preview not working]

Answer (score 0):

Try to close Eclipse and do the following:

1. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
2. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
3. Open Eclipse
4. Re-build

Comment: provide your project for debugging.

Comment: I changed my worksapce and imported my project again. Its working now. but i need to do it everytime to solve this problem??

Comment: I don't know. Do you?

Comment: Do you actually need to create a new workspace everytime? how many times has this occured?

Comment: two times. It gave a message like "read time out, Fast preview may not be working with this project".